# escaping characters in batch using ^

Tags: batch-file

I can get a proper output wuth the below command in the command prompt,
`tasklist /fi "imagename ne siebde*" /fi "imagename eq sieb*" /svc | find "gtwyns"`.

But if i want to use this condition in batch files i have to do this with the below command.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename ne siebde*" /fi "imagename eq sieb*" /svc ^| find "gtwyns")
```

I need to understand the function of ^ character and how does it work actually?

I also wanna know does it open a new cmd when wi use a pipe in batch script?

Comment: you can answer yourself the two questions. You have experienced that the `^` is required in front of `|` in the `for` command. The reason is to escape the `|` char and prevent being interpreted in the bat before passing it to be executed. When you execute it, does the cmd window open?

Comment: @PA The pipe doesn't open a new window, but it does start two new cmd.exe instances (one for each side of the pipe)

Comment: no it does not open a new window..If i elaborate more..

in a batch file i can execute the below command without ^ symbol if i have the below code..

sc \\EDCBSCSR4DE-001 query siebsrvr_VIVO_SES_VIVO_SRVR | find "STOPPED"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (

goto :stopped

) else (

goto :stop

)

Comment: ignore my above comment..here is the new one..

no it does not open a new window..If i elaborate more..

in a batch file i can execute the below command without ^ symbol if i have the below code..

sc \\EDCBSCSR4DE-001 query siebsrvr_VIVO_SES_VIVO_SRVR | find "STOPPED"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (

goto :stopped

) else (

goto :stop

)

But in the below why do i need to use ^ symbol?

for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename ne siebde*" /fi "imagename eq sieb*" /svc ^| find "gtwyns"') do set pid_ns=%%a

echo %pid_ns%

Comment: @learntolive, if a comment is wrong, there is the possibility to delete it... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Read [`FOR /F`: loop command against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) syntax:

> ```
> FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ('command_to_process') DO command
> …
> command_to_process : The output of the 'command_to_process' is passed 
>                      into the FOR parameter.
> ```
>
> … The `command_to_process` can be almost any internal or external
>   command.

Almost any internal or external command (but **the only** command).

Now, read [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) syntax:

> `commandA  |  commandB`     Pipe the output from `commandA` into
>   `commandB`

For instance, in **wrong** `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B | sort /R') do echo %%~a`
with unescaped `|` pipe:

- `commandA` evaluates to `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B` and
- `commandB` evaluates to `sort /R') do echo %%~a` although separate `dir /B | sort /R` is right command.

Hence, we need to [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) (all) `&`, `|`, `<`, `>` redirection characters and (sometimes) `"` double quotes as follows (both ways are equivalent parsing `dir /B "*.vbs" 2>NUL | sort /R` command):

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (' dir /B  "*.vbs" 2^>NUL ^| sort /R ') do echo %%~a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"dir /B ""*.vbs"" 2>NUL  | sort /R"') do echo %%~a
```

Therefore, next two loops should work the same way:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('
    tasklist /fi "imagename ne siebde*" /fi "imagename eq sieb*" /svc ^| find "gtwyns"
  ') do echo set pid_ns=%%a
```

and

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('
  "tasklist /fi ""imagename ne siebde*"" /fi ""imagename eq sieb*"" /svc | find ""gtwyns"""
') do echo set pid_ns=%%a
```